# Update sibling component on mutation?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

Let's assume that I have the following structure:

```
<div>
   <Form />
   <List />
</div>
```

Current setup: query is in `<List />` component and mutation is in `<Form />` component. Because `<Form />` doesn't have query, `getFatQuery` cannot do it's compare magic and it only returns `clientMutationId` which ultimately means that list data doesn't get updated without page refresh.

How could I make this work? I need separate form component because I want to make mutation in modal. Should I make mutation itself in `<List />` and "transport" data from `<Form />` to `<List />`?

I have lots of similar situations where I want to instert data (form component) in separate component, what's the strategy for these situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to do state management with React which, as you note, can be confusing since there is no easy way to "pass data around" components in your hierarchy.

A common solution is to have a parent component hold the data and have your `Form` and `List` components react to this data, changing it only through callbacks passed down from this parent component.

Another common solution is to add Redux to your application to handle the application level state data. This one allows you to keep all data in a single object called a `store`, making it easy for any component to subscribe to changes, therefore eliminating the need for a parent component doing data passing.

Comment: Query and mutation *have to be* on same component in order to get automatic UI updates?

Comment: If that's a question, then the answer is no

Comment: Could you update your answer and expain it with few sentences? Relay.js doesn't update my store (and UI) with new data (mutation payload) if Relay component/query is on different component.

Comment: Was not aware you were using relay, sorry. Not sure how Relay does data updates. Probably ask that part to your code sample.